# UNION ALL on JSON data type

Tags: json, postgresql, compare, union, postgresql-9.2

I need to `UNION ALL` a `JSON` column in Postgres 9.2. But Postgres replies with this error:

> ```
> ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json SQL  
> state: 42883  
> Character: 9
> ```

To the query:

```
(select cast('{"billingcode" : "' || billingcode || '"}' as JSON)
 from billing_2012_08 limit 10)
union
(select cast('{"charged" : "' || charged || '"}' as JSON)
 from sending_response_2012_08 limit 10)
```

What's wrong here?

It seems that Postgres doesn't have an equality operator for the `json` data type.
If this is correct, why?

As an example trying to figure out the problem, this works fine:

```
(select cast('{"billingcode" : "' || billingcode || '"}' as JSON)
 from billing_2012_08 limit 10)
union all
(select cast('{"charged" : "' || charged || '"}' as JSON)
 from sending_response_2012_08 limit 10)
```

Note, `UNION ALL` just "adds" results, as opposed to just `UNION` which eliminates duplicate values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not trivial to test whether JSON values are "equal". Among other things, attributes can be sorted in any order, or there can be any amount of insignificant white space. So the binary or text representation can be completely different while the *value* still qualifies as equal according to JSON specifications. That's why there is **no equality operator** for the data type [**`json`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) in PostgreSQL.

If you are satisfied with the text representations being equal (as it seems from the example) you could `UNION ALL` with a `text` column and cast to `json` later:

```
SELECT json_col::json
FROM (
   (SELECT '{"billingcode" : "' || billingcode || '"}'::text AS json_col
    FROM   billing_2012_08 LIMIT 10)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT '{"charged" : "' || charged || '"}'::text
    FROM   sending_response_2012_08 LIMIT 10)
   ) sub
```

**Or** you can use [**`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) in Postgres 9.4 or later, which comes with the previously missing equality operator (among other things). See:

- [How to remove known elements from a JSON[] array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64765/3684)
- [SELECT UNION from two views of the same table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73531/3684)

Then consider this alternative query:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(t) AS jsonb_col
FROM  (SELECT billingcode FROM billing_2012_08 LIMIT 10) t

UNION
SELECT to_jsonb(t)   -- also preserves possible numeric type!
FROM  (SELECT charged FROM sending_response_2012_08 LIMIT 10) t

ORDER  BY 1;  -- possible with jsonb
```

In addition to `UNION`, `ORDER BY` is also possible now.

Note the use of [**`to_jsonb()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE). By feeding it a *row*, column name(s) are used as key names automatically. This is cleaner and faster and (among other things) preserves possible numeric types, which can affect equality and sort order. ([`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) is also available.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7f296edc73613000057b7076ebcca9ba)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/27757/8)</sub>