# Get unique rows from two tables, but keep duplicates from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, union, distinct

I want to split a table into two tables (or more, but let's say two).

```
table_original
id column1 column2
 1   1        2
 2   1        3
 3   1        4
 4   1        4
 5   1        5
```

We can also assume that `id` is a unique identifier. Now I split this table into two, by using a `CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM table_original WHERE column2 <= 4` and `CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table_original WHERE column2 >= 4`. Now I have these two tables:

```
table1
id column1 column2
 1   1        2
 2   1        3
 3   1        4
 4   1        4
```

```
table2
id column1 column2
 3   1        4
 4   1        4
 5   1        5
```

How to get the same results from those two tables that I can get from the original table? If I run a query `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2` it will be the same as `SELECT * FROM table_original` because of the unique `id` value, however if I run a query `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2` it returns:

```
column1, column2
   1        2
   1        3
   1        4
   1        5
```

which is not the same as `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table_original`, which returns:

```
column1, column2
   1        2
   1        3
   1        4
   1        4
   1        5
```

Duplicates from the same table are removed. However, if I wanted to let's say do a count on duplicates, the results will be different, which is bad. So is there a way to do a `UNION` type operation but keep duplicates that are found in the same table?

Answer (score 2):

The `UNION` on whole rows in your solution will be painfully expensive for big tables (and wide rows). And it fails outright with any column type that doesn't support the equality operator (like `json`). See:

- [UNION ALL on JSON data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836467/union-all-on-json-data-type/18838214#18838214)

This query is *substantially* faster, making use of the unique index on `table1(id)`. (Create that index if you don't have it!)

```sql
SELECT column1, column2
FROM   table1  -- bigger table first to micro-optimize some more

UNION ALL 
SELECT column1, column2
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM table1 WHERE id = t2.id)
```

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

About `UNION ALL` (as opposed to just `UNION`):

- [Is order preserved after UNION in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975969/is-order-preserved-after-union-in-postgresql/31976967#31976967)
- [Combining 3 SELECT statements to output 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348755/combining-3-select-statements-to-output-1-table/59349080#59349080)

The question remains: Why keeps completely duplicate rows in multiple tables?

Comment: Thanks for the optimized query and helpful links. It's just a project I'm testing, where it's possible that from 1 table n tables will be created, and they can also have some duplicate data. However the SELECT query should get the same results as if it was directed to the original table.

Comment: @John: Delete duplicate rows once?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what are you trying to achieve but you need to use `union all`:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2
```

union all keeps the duplicates

Comment: This returns 4x of column1, column2 values of (1,4), which is not the same as if I queried the original table.

Comment: it returns whatever is in both tables , so you should look into your table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer.

To keep the duplicates found in the same table, but eliminate everything else, I used a query `SELECT column1, column2 FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2) AS t;`

This way the UNION uses the unique `id` values to eliminate real duplicates, and after that I just filter the result to get the columns I need.